# Delay in loading the response when I am switching between tabs present in the header of vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have vue component in which I have multiple options(tabs) like "All, Submitted, Rejected etc" on my header. According to the functionality when I click on any of the options, the data for them loads from the api's. I have defined the all the api's on the same component for all the options.

Now when I switch between these options the api with large data takes time to load which is affecting the content of that particular option.

```
               switch (arg) {
                case this.statusVal[0]:
                    this.activate(arg);
                    this
                        .$router
                        .push({
                            name: "sales-approver-dashboard",
                            params: {
                                dropType: this.headerDropdownClaim,
                                approverClaimType: this.statusVal[0]
                            }
                        });
                    this.fetchData()
                    this.claimTableData.claimStatus = "";
                    break;

                  case this.statusVal[1]:
                    this.activate(arg);
                    this
                        .$router
                        .push({
                            name: "sales-approver-dashboard",
                            params: {
                                dropType: this.headerDropdownClaim,
                                approverClaimType: this.statusVal[1]
                            }
                        });
                    this.fetchData()
                    this.claimTableData.claimStatus = this.statusVal[1];
                    break;
```

the fetchData() functions calls the post request which has the response containing the data of each options. So when I quickly move between these options, the response with large data is taking more time to load while I am already in the different tab having less data whose response is already loaded but it is showing the data of last loaded response(as it contains the large amount of data)

Edited question

1. I am opening the dashboard having different tabs/options to switch between.
2. On first load api with data is calling having all the data.
3. I am calling the fetchData function which is basically displaying the data through post request and taking the response only which is required on that page based on the pages/tabs.
4. I am switching between the tabs through routing of vue js as above code (case1, case2) and each tab is again calling that fetchData function which shows the data based on that tab.
5. So when I routes between tabs, suppose I have large response for first tab and very less for the tab on which I have moved on. So what is happening in that case, that previous page fetchData function is still in execution but I have routed to next page which has less response let's say only one data. Because of that it loads quickly but the previous function is still in execution and loads after the this one.

Because of that the data of 2nd tabs loads first and I am able to see that data on screen but as soon as the first function is executed that data is now displayed on the screen which is wrong.
So is there any solution like we can stop the execution of that previous function as soon as route to next page.

Comment: You could probably use `keep-alive` here: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html#keepalive to cache the state (especially if it's not being updated often). Or do a check on every activation if needed.

Comment: Should it work in first load also as I switch quickly between the tabs it doesn't know which data to display? So whichever response is loaded at the end will be displayed.
@kissu

Comment: As shown in the given doc, if you use a dynamic component with it's own state, it will keep it's local state. So you should not have any issues regarding data splitting. Of course, you need to have them in separate instance of course, there is no benefit on overwriting it in the same shared instance.

Comment: But I am using these all tabs in same component and all are wrapped in div's. So how can I use this here?

Comment: Create a instance of a Vue component for each tab so. Otherwise, if it's in the same place why/how do you even fetch them again? Some [repro]/minimal effort would be appreciated here.

Comment: Now I have a proper question: I have am calling the api on page load and it has some data. Now I am calling another function which basically have a post request and getting a response of the data which i need on that page. So  when i am routing to next page the function is still calling because of its large data. So all I want to do is when i route to other page destroy the execution of that function. @kissu

Comment: Have to say that it's pretty unclear. Do you have some code example to illustrate that?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope you can understand now. @kissu

Comment: Why are you calling the `asyncData` function again? It's meant for the page, if you want to load a small amount of data per tab, call a dedicated function for the tab rather than calling the bigger one for the whole page. Depending on how you call the function for that, you can cancel it midair (while it's sent and not resolved yet). You can google for that specific case. Mostly, you can optimize things in various ways (like pagination + lazy loading with Intersection API etc) but you can also keep your components' state cached between each tab change. Do you even need to cancel the 1st one?

Comment: Also, if the data from the 2nd tab is taking less time but being replaced by 1st tab's data, there is an issue regarding your state implementation. You should not have common space for them IMO. If it's really needed, you can of course cancel the call as you wanted. But this data seems quite huge if it's happening so I think there might be another issue here.